# Import Python UDFs

Tags: python

While trying import Python UDFs created from myproject.py there is an error

```
Run-time error '1000' in Visual Basic
Function Py()
    XLPyLoadDLL
    If 0 <> XLPyDLLActivateAuto(Py, XLPyCommand) Then Err.Raise 1000, Description:=Py
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It probably because `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` is not in the PYTHONPATH. You have to tell/configure Visuall Basic where to find either the python.exe or pythonw.ext executable.