# xlwings error 1000 can't seem to launch dll? XLPyDLLActivateAuto?

Tags: xlwings

I'm receiving an error 1000.  I've tried so many things to fix.  It seems that it fail at XLPyDLLActivateAuto.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While there is no definitive fix there is some debugging and suggestions on xlwings github for that error **https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/764** and maybe **https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/766**. Have you gone thru those suggestions?

Comment: ALso a previous question **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210452/import-python-udfs** might help.